# Adding String to Content Control Box / Replace Dropdown with Content Control

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, contentcontrol

I've got a working code but I'd like to replace my Drop-Down with Content Control, because I need to be able to also manually type in a value.
The value inside is a list from a https, this string works completely fine, so please ignore.

Here's my code:

```
Dim MyRequest As Object
Dim Data() As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim maxi As Integer

    Set MyRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    MyRequest.Open "GET", _
    "https... (This is hidden for security resons, /csv/)"

    ' Send Request.
    MyRequest.Send

    'And we get this response
    'MsgBox MyRequest.ResponseText
    Data = Split(MyRequest.ResponseText, "|")

    If UBound(Data()) > 25 Then
        maxi = 25
    Else
        maxi = UBound(Data())
    End If


    For j = 1 To 6
        ActiveDocument.FormFields("Dropdown" & j).DropDown.ListEntries.Clear
        For i = 0 To maxi - 1
            ActiveDocument.FormFields("Dropdown" & j).DropDown.ListEntries.Add Name:=Data(i)
        Next i
    Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: Here is Greg Maxey's page on using VBA with Content Controls versus FormFields: https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/content_controls.html Microsoft's reference page is also worth a read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/working-with-word/working-with-content-controls

Answer (score 0):

You should not use content controls and formfields in the same document. They were not designed to be used that way and doing so is a known source of problems.

As you observed, dropdown formfields don’t support text entry. To provide that facility, you could provide an option in the dropdown for 'free text' and use an on-exit macro with an Inputbox to insert the user’s 'free text' into the dropdown. For example, suppose you have a dropdown with 5 items, the last of which offers free text entry (e.g. an 'Other' option). Adding the following on-exit macro to the formfield will provide that:

```
Sub FreeText()
Dim StrNew As String, i As Long
With Selection.FormFields(1).DropDown
  i = .ListEntries.Count
  If .Value = i Then
    StrNew = Trim(InputBox("Input your text", "Data Entry", .ListEntries(i).Name))
    If StrNew = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
      .ListEntries(i).Delete
      .ListEntries.Add StrNew
      .Value = i
  End If
End With
End Sub
```